# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisClusterConfiguration

Tags: spring

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/redis/connection/RedisClusterConfiguration
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:613)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:524)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:510)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:570)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:697)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:640)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:609)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1484)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:425)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:395)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:508)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1189)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromMappedException(SpringApplication.java:862)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromException(SpringApplication.java:848)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleExitCode(SpringApplication.java:834)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:788)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:325)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151)
    at com.example.RedisCacheExample.RedisCacheExampleApplication.main(RedisCacheExampleApplication.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisClusterConfiguration
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 24 more
```

////////

```
package config;

/**
 * Created by desmond on 15/5/2017.
 */

import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.CachingConfigurerSupport;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCacheManager;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate;

@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfig extends CachingConfigurerSupport {

    @Bean
    public JedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
        JedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory();

        // Defaults
        redisConnectionFactory.setHostName("127.0.0.1");
        redisConnectionFactory.setPort(6379);
        return redisConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory cf) {
        RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<String, String>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(cf);
        return redisTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager(RedisTemplate redisTemplate) {
        RedisCacheManager cacheManager = new RedisCacheManager(redisTemplate);

        // Number of seconds before expiration. Defaults to unlimited (0)
        cacheManager.setDefaultExpiration(300);
        return cacheManager;
    }
}
```

I am trying spring with redis. I followed a tutorial online but it is giving this error. I have downloaded redis and it is running in my background. What am i doing wrong here? I have included the error above and the redis code. please help me thank you. The pom file is added below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>RedisCacheExample</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>RedisCacheExample</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: Does your project compile? It seem that the missing class was relesead in spring-data-redis 1.7 and you are using 1.6.2.RELEASE http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/connection/RedisClusterConfiguration.html

Comment: @RubioRic Thanks it works when i changed it!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to help. :-)